# In RxJS, map not executing inner mapped observable

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

New to RxJS, but I'm trying to map a single element stream to another that produces an array *after* all internal/subsequent streams are finished/loaded.  However, my inner observables don't seem to be executing.  They just get returned cold.

High level, I need to execute http post to upload a list of files (in two different arrays to two different endpoints).  Since they are large I emulate with a delay of 5 seconds.  The requests need to be executed in parallel, but limited to concurrently executing X at a time (here 2).  This all needs to be inside a pipe and the pipe should only allow the stream to continue *after* all posts are complete.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pnwa1b

```
import { map, mapTo, mergeMap, mergeAll, delay, tap, catchError, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { interval, merge, forkJoin, of, from, range, Observable } from 'rxjs';

const single = "name";

const first = ["abc", "def"];

const second = of("ghi", "jkl", "mno");

of(single)
.pipe(tap(val => console.log(`emit:${val}`)))
.pipe(
  map(claim => 
    merge(
      from(first).pipe(map(photo => of(photo).pipe(delay(5000)))),
      from(second).pipe(map(video => of(video).pipe(delay(5000))))
    )
    .pipe(
      mergeAll(2)
    )
    .pipe(tap(val => console.log(`emit:${val}`)))
    .pipe(toArray())
    .pipe(tap(val => console.log(`emit:${val}`)))
  )
)
.pipe(
catchError(error => {
  console.log("error");
  return Observable.throw(error);
})
)
.subscribe(val => console.log(`final:${val}`));
```

An inner subscribe would not wait until they are complete.  Using forkJoin would not allow me to limit the concurrent uploads.  How can I accomplish this?

**Update:**

Answer by @dmcgrandle was very helpful and led me to make the changes below that seem to be working:

```
import { map, mapTo, mergeMap, mergeAll, delay, tap, catchError, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { interval, merge, forkJoin, of, from, range, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

const single = "name";

const first = ["abc", "def"];

const second = of("ghi", "jkl", "mno");

of(single)
.pipe(tap(val => console.log(`emit:${val}`)))
.pipe(
  mergeMap(claim =>
    merge(
      from(first).pipe(map(photo => of(photo).pipe(delay(5000)).pipe(tap(val => console.log(`emit:${val}`))))),
      from(second).pipe(map(video => of(video).pipe(delay(5000)).pipe(tap(val => console.log(`emit:${val}`)))))
    )
  ),
  mergeAll(2),
  toArray()
)
.pipe(
catchError(error => {
  console.log("error");
  return throwError(error);
})
)
.subscribe(val => console.log(`final:${val}`));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, then I think this is a solution.  Your issue was with the first `map`, which won't perform an inner subscribe, but rather just transform the stream into Observables of Observables, which didn't seem to be what you wanted.  Instead I used `mergeMap` there.

Inside the `from`'s I used concatMap to force each emission from `first` and `second` to happen in order and wait for one to complete before another started.  I also set up `postToEndpoint` functions that return Observables to be closer to what your actual code will probably look like.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-54258333?file=index.ts) Demo

code:

```
import { mergeMap, concatMap, delay, tap, catchError, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { merge, of, from, concat, throwError } from 'rxjs';

const single = "name";

const first = ["abc", "def"];

const second = of("ghi", "jkl", "mno");

const postToEndpoint1$ = photo => of(photo).pipe(
  tap(data => console.log('start of postTo1 for photo:', photo)),
  delay(5000),
  tap(data => console.log('end of postTo1 for photo:', photo))
);

const postToEndpoint2$ = video => of(video).pipe(
  tap(data => console.log('start of postTo2 for video:', video)),
  delay(5000),
  tap(data => console.log('end of postTo2 for video:', video))
);

of(single).pipe(
  tap(val => console.log(`initial emit:${val}`)),
  mergeMap(claim => 
    merge(
      from(first).pipe(concatMap(postToEndpoint1$)),
      from(second).pipe(concatMap(postToEndpoint2$))
      )
  ),
  toArray(),
  catchError(error => {
    console.log("error");
    return throwError(error);
  })
).subscribe(val => console.log(`final:`, val));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: extremely helpful.  The postToEndpoints made things more clear.  I was hoping to merge the arrays prior to the concurrency limit/throttling so that (a) it could handle one array being much larger than the other and (b) I could increase the concurrency limit to 5 or so.  Your answer led me to the changes that I needed to accomplish this (see update in original post).

Comment: If it led you to the correct solution, sure.  Note the guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) which says "Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly".  But as the guidance also says, you should not feel compelled to accept an answer if you don't want to.  :)  Either way, I am glad you got it sorted.  Happy coding.